# How to check the iOS 5 application with iOS 6

Tags: ios

I am developing an iOS application with iOS 5, now I want to check the application with ios6. I am using xcode 4.2, and iOS 5.1. I want to check my application with iOS 6 simulator.

How to achieve this? Has any option for integrate iOS 6 simulator to xcode 4.2? Is only option use xcode 4.5?

Comment: I think you need to install xcode 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS6 SDK and thus the iOS6 Simulator is only included with Xcode 4.5 so you will have to upgrade your Xcode to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to "check", it is doable. You will need to install Xcode 4.5 (not upgrade, keep your 4.2). Do all your code changing in Xcode 4.2 and you can run your application in Xcode 4.5 with iOS 6 simulator by selecting "Product > Perform Action > Run Without Building". This also works for iPhone 5 simulator.